# Eclipse Java, Send email from Gmail SMTP programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email programmatically using Java, in Eclipse. I have the project set up properly, using the most recent JDK 1.8.0_45. By which I mean I have included `mailapi.jar` and `smtp.jar`.

I have read numerous other posts on the topic, and I know my Java build path must include `mail.jar`. However, when I searched the folder, no `mail.jar` was found; `mailapi.jar` was the closest and seems to resolve the include errors I was getting without it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class emailer {

    private static String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private static String user = "**********";
    private static String pass = "***********";

    public static void sendEmail(String fromAddr, String toAddr, String subject, String body)
    {
        Properties prop = System.getProperties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try
        {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddr));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddr));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, user, pass);
            transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients()); 
            //The above line has a warning message
            //"The static method send(Message, Address[]) from the type Transport should be accessed in a static way"
            transport.close();
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        catch (AddressException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

The code compiles without errors, and upon running, continues to run indefinitely, never breaking nor stopping. So unfortunately I do not have a stack trace to show... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Recommend using apache commons mail https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html There actually is a gmail sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the outgoing port to 587 and not 465. That get's rid of the infinite timeout (since `Transport` has no timeout value). Also, using the static `Transport.send()` will simplify your code a lot (I also did get some errors when using the non-static method). So something like this.

```
public class Emailer  //Class names should always be capitalized
{

private static String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
private static String user = "**********";
private static String pass = "***********";

public static void sendEmail(String fromAddr, String toAddr, String subject, String body)
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    Session.getInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try
    {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddr));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddr));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        Transport.send(message, user, pass);
    }
    catch (AddressException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Upon making these changes, I get the following stack trace.

Comment: sorry, error + stack trace was much to large to fit in a comment.

error :
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

I don't understand this, because I have set up my gmail account for less secure app access, so the authentication shouldn't fail

Comment: stack trace

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:893)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:265)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:251)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:174)
 at emailer.sendEmail(emailer.java:32)
 at run.main(run.java:5)

Comment: The above code works fine for me. Are you sure your username and password are correct?

Comment: I am sure; have double checked

Comment: My less secure app access was disabled again... fixed that, and it works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to include javax.mail.jar

here's the homepage where you can download it from

https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

Comment: Done the above, program still just runs continuously without breaking or completing... I do know that my code is attempting to use gmail's smtp server, as I received an email message from google notifying me of the attempt to access my account, at which point I turned on less secure app access to allow my program to access the gmail smtp.